# Server stores same Querystring value asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, request.querystring

I have used `QueryString` to take value from clicked menu, on redirect I filter values of page on basis of `QueryString` value. 
But every time `Request.QueryString` returns the same value even if there are different value in url. On ASPX page I written below code

```
    Response.Write("<a href='../SubCategory.aspx?SubCategoryID=" + subcatArrayID5.ElementAt(i) + "'>" + subcatArrayName5.ElementAt(i) + "</a>");
```

and access it using below code in SubCategory.aspx Page

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) { 
    if (Request.QueryString["SubCategoryID"] != null) { 
        SubCategoryID = Request.QueryString["SubCategoryID"].ToString(); 
        Div1.InnerHtml = Request.QueryString["SubCategoryID"]; 
    } 
    Databind(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are accessing the values of `QueryString`?

Comment: Can you also type the code that re-directs to the other page based on this value?

Comment: Could you add all that to the question itself? Just for readability purposes

Comment: @DIe i have added code in question now.

Comment: @Ahmad  i have added code in question now

Comment: I don't see any page redirection. You are only modifying a link on the page. Are you sure this is all the code that has to do with re-directing? Where is `Response.Redirect()` ?

Comment: @Ahmad I am dynamically making <a> tag in aspx form so there is no need of response.redirect()

Comment: So the problem is that the link inside the `<a>` element is not correct?

Comment: No..Problem is after redirection, if first tym value is 1 then it remains same for all other redirects even if other querystring values are 2 or 3 or 4..provided values in url are correct.

Comment: Don't say redirect if you're not actually redirecting. You're just confusing things. Clicking on a hyperlink is not a redirect.